# How to profile the budget usage of Plutus scripts

Tags: plutus, decentralized-applications, development

How to profile the budget usage of Plutus scripts

https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howtos/profiling-scripts.html?highlight=profiling

Im struggling trying to follow the steps indicated in the howto to get the profiling of the scripts.

I added this line for the compiler, in the file where the mkValidator is:
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin-opt PlutusTx.Plugin:profile-all #-}

I compiled my code with cabal build.

Then It says you must execute:

uplc evaluate -i myscript.flat --if flat --trace-mode LogsWithBudgets -o logs

But can't find uplc anywhere.

Neither I find the output myscript.flat anywhere.

It says that "All the executables referred to here can be built from the plutus repository using cabal build"

I have the lates Plutus Apps and already built with Nix and cabal build but can't find the uplc.

It mentions after that you uses traceToStacks, another exe, to convert the results. Can't find this exe and can't execute with cabal exec traceToStacks neither.

If you did this profiling on your scripts I'll be very happy to know about it.

Thank you!!!